# Vertices of Polytope using Gurobi

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra

Is there any way I can obtain all the vertices of a polytope using Gurobi?

If this isn't possible, can I log all the intermediate vertices that Simplex finds before it hits the optimal one?

Comment: Have you looked at this question: [How to find all vertices of a polyhedron](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4540/how-to-find-all-vertices-of-a-polyhedron)?