# Simplex Method Manual pivoting in GLPK for a Warm Start

Tags: linear-programming, solver, simplex, api, warm-start

My question is kind of related to [this 2015 post at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533831/find-all-alternative-basic-solutions-using-existing-linear-programming-tool).

About Simplex method tableau pivoting in Linear Programming -- this is proving to be difficult in GLPK.. I am using Linux, GLPK 5.0 version, in C language.. I want to do this so as to obtain multiple (alternate) **basic** optimal solutions (Optimal *BFS*, or Optimal *Extreme Points*).

Is it sufficient to specify the variable entering the basis?  Or do I need to specify both the entering variable **and** the variable leaving the basis?

What I have tried so far:

```
probA = glp_create_prob();
glp_read_lp(probA, NULL, "Model-Old.lp");   // Read original LP model (in CPLEX LP format)
glp_read_sol(probA, "basic-solution-old.txt");  // Load basic solution created earlier
glp_set_col_stat(probA, 2, GLP_BS);   // Set variable x2 to enter the basis
glp_set_col_stat(probA, 4, GLP_NL);   // Set x4 to leave the basis (and become zero)
glp_simplex(probA, GLP_OFF);   // Turn off Pre-solver and solve the new problem.
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work (I have tried with different entering and leaving variables)..  How can I fix the code above?  Or is there a better way to do re-optimisation in GLPK (with C language)?  Thanks.

**Edit**: I looked up my favourite book in Linear Programming, by George Hadley (this was the *textbook* we followed 35 years ago, in 1987!).. In Section 5-7 (Page 166), he describes a method to reach alternate optimal BFS by pivoting.. I'm trying to implement this (don't know if there are better approaches now).

(I've just been reading [this answer a few months ago from Henrik Friberg](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7996/can-the-primal-simplex-method-walk-all-optima-in-linear-time/8031#8031).)

Comment: One possible way to achieve multiple optimal solutions is, you would need to check the optimal tableau of the simplex iterations. (usually the last one). If there exist non-basic variables with the zero reduced cost it might be a signal to existing such a solution.

Comment: Yes, I know, but my question is specifically about re-optimisation (warm start) using GLPK.

Comment: Are you interested *all*, *just some*, or *some specific* alternative optima?

Comment: To Sune -- I am interested in all OEP (optimal extreme points).

Comment: Interestingly, you can enumerate all basic feasible solutions by encoding the basis with binary variables (1=basic,0=non-basic). Then use no-good constraints to forbid a previous solution.  See: https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions.html (there I enumerate all optimal bases, but this can be adapted to enumerate all feasible bases).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid Integer Programming since it is NP-hard! But thanks anyway.. I'm now also looking at [CDD software](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/fukudak/cdd_home/) developed by [Komei Fukuda](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/fukudak/) at ETH Zurich.

Comment: Had too many problems installing [polymake](https://polymake.org/) in Ubuntu Linux.. so had to abandon that.